# Calculate the probability of winning a specific number of games if each individual game has a different probability of winning?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Say I have to play 11 games. My goal is to win at least 6, and each game has a DIFFERENT probability of being won.

The probabilities of winning each game (as a %) are as follows: 24, 59, 3, 10, 85, 47, 14, 69, 92, 57, 63.

How can I calculate the probability that I will win at least 6 out of 11 of these games, in any particular combination of 6 wins?

This is something I am trying to implement in Java.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: As you surmise, it is messy to do it exactly.  As a practical matter, just simulate it.  That's almost always good enough and should be easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly calculate the probability of winning "at least six games" I would calculate the probability of winning "five or fewer games" and subtract from 1.  Since you have different probabilities of winning each game that will still be tedious!

Let's look at a simpler problem where you want to win 3 out of 5 games with probability of winng a, b, c, d, e.

I would calculate the probablity of winning 0, 1, or 2 games then subtract from 1.

The probability of not winning each of the games is 1- a, 1- b, 1- c, 1- e, and 1- e.

The probability of winning NO games is
(1- a)(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)(1- e).

The probability of exactly one game is
a(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)(1- b)c(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)(1- b)(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)e.

The probability of exactly two wins is ab(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ a(1- b)c(1- d)(1- e)+ a(1-b)c(1- d)(1- e)+ a((1- b)(1- c)d(1- e)+ a(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)e+ (1- a)bc(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)(1- d)e.

The probability of "two or less" is the sum of those:

(1- a)(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ a(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)(1- b)c(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)(1- b)(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)e+ ab(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ a(1- b)c(1- d)(1- e)+ a(1-b)c(1- d)(1- e)+ a((1- b)(1- c)d(1- e)+ a(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)e+ (1- a)bc(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)(1- d)e.

The probability of "three or more" is 1 minus that:
1- (1- a)(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ a(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)(1- b)c(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)(1- b)(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)e+ ab(1- c)(1- d)(1- e)+ a(1- b)c(1- d)(1- e)+ a(1-b)c(1- d)(1- e)+ a((1- b)(1- c)d(1- e)+ a(1- b)(1- c)(1- d)e+ (1- a)bc(1- d)(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)d(1- e)+ (1- a)b(1- c)(1- d)e.